# Proof of closedness of discrete subgroup of a topological group

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, topological-groups

Here is a lemma of [John Ratcliffe's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=JV9m8o-ok6YC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> **Lemma:** If $G$ is a topological group with a metric topology, then every
>   discrete subgroup of $G$ is closed in $G$.

*Proof.* Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$ and suppose that $G − \Gamma$ is not
open. Then there is a $g$ in $G − \Gamma$ and $g_n$ in $B(g, 1/n) \cap \Gamma$ for each integer
$n > 0$. As $g_n \to g$ in $G$, we have that $g_ng_{n+1}^{-1}
\to 1$ in $\Gamma$. **But $\{g_ng_{n+1}^{-1}\}$
is not eventually constant**, which contradicts Lemma 2. Therefore, the set
$G − \Gamma$ must be open, and so $\Gamma$ is closed in $G$.

**Q1:** Why is it clear that $\{g_ng_{n+1}^{-1}\}$
is not eventually constant?

**Q2:** Is metric topology important here? (I think being Hausdorff suffices.)

Comment: The fact that we can use sequences uses the metric too.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508366/4280) is an almost duplicate.

Comment: [Proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_Subgroup_of_Hausdorff_Group_is_Closed) also treats it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: By this post I don't meant a proof for closedness I just want to understand this proof.

Comment: Well, in *this proof* the metric is important but this was to adress Q2: it still holds more generally but the author of the book doesn't need that.

Comment: The point is, as @diracdeltafunk rightly makes, is that if $g_n g^{-1}_{n+1}$ is eventually constant so would the $(g_n)$ sequence be eventually constant (so equal to $g$!). And this cannot happen in a discrete set as the limit is outside the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ${g_n g_{n+1}^{-1}}$ were eventually constant (let's say $g_n g_{n+1}^{-1} = g_m g_{m+1}^{-1}$ for all $n,m \geq N$, where $N$ is some fixed natural number), then the limit of the sequence (which is unique because metric topologies are Hausdorff) would be $g_N g_{N+1}^{-1}$. At the same time, the limit of the sequence is $1$, so $g_n g_{n+1}^{-1} = 1$ for all $n \geq N$. This means that $g_n = g_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq N$, and thus $g_n \to g_N$. Since $g_n \to g$, w have $g = g_N$. This is a contradiction because $g \in G - \Gamma$ but $g_N \in \Gamma$.

Edit: to answer your second question, the metric is actually used in this argument to get the sequence $g_n$. But you're right that Hausdorff is all that you really need: suppose $G$ is Hausdorff and $\Gamma$ is a non-closed discrete subgroup. Then there is some limit point $g$ of $\Gamma$ such that $g \notin \Gamma$. Take a sequence $g_n \to g$ with each $g_n \in \Gamma$ and use the same argument as in this proof. It's perhaps a little harder to see that $\{g_n g_{n+1}^{-1}\}$ must be convergent, but it's still doable:

Let $U$ be an open set containing $1$. Let $V = \{(x,y) \in G \times G : xy^{-1} \in U\}$. $V$ is also open because $G$ is a topological group. The sequence $\{(g_n, g_{n+1})\}$ converges to $(1,1)$, so there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(g_n, g_{n+1}) \in V$ for all $n \geq N$. This means that $g_n g_{n+1}^{-1} \in U$ for all $n \geq N$, and since $U$ was an arbitrary open neighborhood of $1$, we have that $g_n g_{n+1}^{-1} \to 1$.

**Edit 2** The first edit is wrong – the result is still true in general when $G$ is Hausdorff, but my proof assumes that "$\Gamma$ is not closed" implies "there exists a sequence in $G - \Gamma$ which converges to a point in $\Gamma$", which is not true in all topological spaces! We need to use a different argument; thanks to @HennoBrandsma for linking to [this relatively simple approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29515/4280).

Comment: In general you cannot get a sequence but will get a net. I don't see an analogue for $g_n g_{n+1}^{-1}$ as clearly in that general case. So metric seems really needed.

Comment: Ah you're right, for my argument we actually need $G$ to be a sequential space; equivalently $G$ needs to be a quotient of some metric space. I'm pretty sure the result holds for general Hausdorff groups though – I'll try to come up with a different proof or counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29515/4280) helps? It does seem to be a general Hausdorff fact but the proofs are more tricky, and the OP works in a metric setting anyway..

Comment: Good find, thank you!

Comment: I find the [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_Subgroup_of_Hausdorff_Group_is_Closed) proof quite readable and short in this case. (not always :))